# Misspelled tags, how to fix?

Tags: support, tags

Rather ironically, the OP on this question misspelled [spelling](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) so we now have a tag called [spelign](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelign).

[Verify the automatic language detection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269923/verify-the-automatic-language-detection)

How are these dealt with?

I didn't just want to retag it [spelling](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) or [spell-check](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spell-check) as I'm not sure what that would then do with the orphaned tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open a meta question or ask a mod for help with this kind of thing — just retag the question with the correct tag spelling. At 3:00 UTC all tags with zero questions are automatically deleted. A mod using the tag merge functionality creates a tag synonym, which is obviously incorrect in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Tag merging to the rescue!

Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. In future would it be sufficient to to link to something like this in chat & see if a mod picks it up?

Comment: We get notified if a post is flagged or a question is asked on Meta, so this works better than just posting to chat.

Comment: Can the pointless synonym be deleted now?

Comment: @grgarside Yepp, as soon as I'm in front of a real computer again :-)

Comment: That's the issue these days, isn't it? I use a computer so rarely now that I don't come here nearly as often as I once did.

Comment: @Daniel Absolutely. Unfortunately the mod functions are hard to access/use from an iPhone